# global-auto-revert-mode with confirmation first?

Tags: buffers, files, revert-buffer

I know I can use `(global-auto-revert-mode 1)` to automatically revert a buffer if the buffer has been changed in another editor.

However, when Emacs detects (automatically) that the buffer has changed, I would prefer it then to **ask** me whether I want to revert this buffer or not. Is there a way for it?

Comment: It looks like this is the kind of thing you're looking for? https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoRevertMode#toc2  . I don't have the time to test/write it up as a proper answer,

Comment: @MarkDunne Yes, this is what I asked for, thanks. It seems the code is not tested well, but well, "something" is better than nothing.